# eager loading return null on one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

i have three table which have sort of many to many relationship
the table name: notes(id,user_id,card_id,body), Users(id,name,password,...), Card(id,cardname,cardText)
now i want to use eager loading to get the related user name
i have three model which represented like here:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{
    /*public $table= 'Fake';*/
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;
    public function cards()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Card::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
    }

}
```

and in my route i used following:

```
<?php

use App\Card;
Route::get('/', function () {
    $card=new Card();
    $card->id=1;
    $card->load('notes.users')->all();
    return $card;
});
```

but i don't know why i get null in user in json:
the json file:

```
{
id: 1,
notes: [
{
id: 1,
card_id: 1,
user_id: 1,
body: "Hussein Jafari",
users: null
},
{
id: 2,
card_id: 1,
user_id: 1,
body: "Ammpeaa",
users: null
},
{
id: 12,
card_id: 1,
user_id: 1,
body: "KAIRIMI SANJABI",
users: null
},
{
id: 13,
card_id: 1,
user_id: 1,
body: "MOAHAHS KASK KSK",
users: null
},
{
id: 14,
card_id: 1,
user_id: 1,
body: "bENAJAJ KSAK KS",
users: null
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your relation in `Note` class as:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', id);
}
```

It is because eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with `_id`.

But in your case, it was looking for `users_id` column.

OR

You can change the relation name as:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then eager load as:

```
$card->load('notes.user')->all();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: thanks for replay, i did it but i still get user as null just like above json. no different

Comment: Then make sure that there is User with `id` 1 in your DB.

Comment: the user id in db are 1,2,3 and all of them has record in notes table but why u say user with id one we didn't mention user in our query we just want user which register card with id one and their related notes

Comment: By looking at your JSON file especially `user_id` in `notes` node, just to make sure that there is related user in DB.